# PHP APC installation failed on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, apc

I have done this

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev make libpcre3-dev
```

and then

```
sudo pecl install apc
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
                         ^
make: *** [apc_compile.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Do you have idea what can be issue? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Why do you install PHP over the package manager and APC over PECL?

```
apt-get install php-apc
```

is much easier and you get the correct package for APC.

Comment: I have done "apt-get install php-apc" and then "sudo pecl install pac" and again the same error

Comment: You don't need pecl. You have installed the package over the package manager. Restart PHP / Apache and its working.

Comment: With "apt-get install php-apc".

Comment: Please also refer : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65731              [2013-09-21 14:38 UTC] rasmus@php.net
-Status: Open
+Status: Suspended
 [2013-09-21 14:38 UTC] rasmus@php.net
APC doesn't support PHP 5.5. PHP 5.5 comes bundled with an opcode cache now.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to the answer mentioned as correct. I got

> Package 'php-apc' has no installation candidate

when tried to install with `sudo apt-get install php-apc`. So try `sudo apt-get install php-apcu` and use `apcu` instead of `apc` everywhere.